# print to pdf jupyter notebook containing javascript live plots

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, save

I have a jupyter notebook which I am trying to save (I need a static copy of it).

The notebook has various plots in it and, among them, few "live plots" that use javascript (I might be able to obtain them using matplotlib if needed).

I tried to save the notebook to pdf but the live plots are entirely skipped and the cells with long code or with wide tables extend over the margins and are not correctly displayed.

I also tried to save it to slide.html but can't see anything except the first slide (and the directional arrows do not seem to work, so I can't move to the next slide).

The only way I managed to create a static copy was by saving it as html.

Any suggestion on how to proceed?